# Why is there a linux tag?

Tags: discussion, retagging

In theory, all questions on the **unix**-stackexchange could be tagged **linux**?

Isn't it then a bit redundant to have a **linux** tag? *OR* is it there to discriminate between linux or unix specific questions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think it is good to have the **linux** tag for posts that are linux-specific.  That is, the linux tag should be used when the answer applies to linux but not other unices such as Solaris.

Answer (score 12):

It does make sense for the reason [Steven said](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109/why-is-there-a-linux-tag/110#110) -- to mark questions that are Linux-specific. Unfortunately, I think it's likely to get put on lots of questions that aren't actually Linux-specific, just like distro tags will get put on questions that aren't distro-specific. There are even 18 questions right now [tagged with both [linux] and [unix]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linux+unix), which is fairly ridiculous, but I think we'll just have to handle those cases manually (xeno has been pretty active at removing tags that shouldn't be on questions)

Comment: +1, lol... it seems one user in particular likes to overtag

Comment: I remove them if I think they are not, but I'll be honest that I don't have enough BSD, etc, experience to be sure.

Comment: mm... maybe this issue will resolve itself by social pressures as unix SE matures?

Comment: Does this answer need updating? I am concerned by the *18 questions* part.

Comment: I'm not updating this every time somebody retags a question; there were 18 questions as of 7 Sep 2010