# Kill the unix tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I've just gone and removed the [unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unix) tag from many questions. It's mostly used on questions migrated from other Stack Exchange sites, on poorly tagged questions, and on questions about the original AT&T Unix product.

I propose using [att-unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/att-unix) instead and banning [unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unix).

See also previous discussion on this tag:
[Tags for variant-agnostic questions](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168/tags-for-variant-agnostic-questions)

Comment: Gnu/Linux is Unix, but not UNIX. UNIX is the (original) AT&T version of Unix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `unix` tag is now banned.](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/561/the-linux-tag-is-not-allowed/565#565)

It hasn't been eradicated from the questions that have is, but it can no longer be added to a question, and any edit to a question that still has it must remove it.

Answer (score 14):

We have a concept now of intrinsic / ambient tags per site, that is

- the [apple] tag on apple.se
- the [wordpress] tag on wordpress.se
- the [programming] tag on stackoverflow

etc, etc.

These tags are disallowed and also removed from any migrated questions -- but they are tested prior to migration to make sure the migrated question has at least 1 tag in common with the target site.

I added `^(unix|linux)$` to the intrinsic tags for this site.

Comment: Not the `linux` tag! It's heavily used, and legitimate, to mark questions that are specific to Linux (as opposed to portable between unix variants).

Comment: @gilles I'm checking the code and intrinsic tags are mostly checked on migrations. It is not blacklisted for normal questions asked on the site. Let me know if that's not the case but I believe it to be true.

Comment: I think this makes sense for migrated questions, as people from, for example, SO have no idea about our policy on the linux tag here.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not a big fan of using [att-unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/att-unix); people trying to use [unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unix) legitimately have no way of knowing we've named the tag something else. I'd rather retaggers just monitor [unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unix) and remove it from posts that should've have it (the same thing we do with lots of tags already). If it's a problem of incoming posts, there's a [list of recently migrated posts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tools/recently-imported) that can help

Comment: Is there a way to get all the useful tools in a feed? Or is that impossible because they require authentication? Oh, and migrated questions don't even appear in the new question feed!

Comment: @Gilles They do appear in the feed now; [Tshepang noticed when it happened](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/26?m=535980#535980). I don't know of a way to get 10k lists in a feed, for the reason you said

Comment: Maybe they're supposed to, but I see neither of [today's](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8720/printing-conjunct-unicode-characters-using-single-keystroke) [imports](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8708/debian-security-etc-permissions) in the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/620693#620693).

Comment: @Gilles Oh, interesting. They keep their old timestamps; I  bet they only show up if they're migrated soon enough that they're still newer than the oldest post on the feed

Comment: [Tshepang requested the feature](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81113/make-migrated-posts-be-part-of-chat-rss-feed) but went unnoticed.