# The linux tag is not allowed

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

When retagging a question (either with the tag editor or with the question editor), I can't add the [linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linux) tag. This happens both with Chrome and Firefox.

> Couldn't save tags because:
>
> - sorry, the 'linux' tag is not allowed.

[image: sorry, the 'linux' tag is not allowed.]

Other tag edits seem to work normally.

If [linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linux) has been added to the blacklist: no! That would be like blacklisting `windows` on SU.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We changed the rules so intrinsic tags are inherently blacklisted across all sites.

(an intrinsic tag is "apple" on apple.se, "wordpress" on wordpress.se, etc etc etc etc.  See https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/514/5132 for some more details.)

We can remove "linux" as an intrinsic tag -- "unix" is also intrinsic here -- but this means you will get questions tagged "linux" migrated here without the tag removed.

Comment: Yes, please remove `linux`. Linux is only a subset of the site's topic (a very large subset, but still a subset). It's normal to have it as a tag.

Comment: @gilles OK done

Comment: Agree with Gilles. The example with Apple on apple.se is not the same. Single site, single subject, tag blacklisted :)

Comment: In a site called `Tom & Jerry`: why `Tom` should be blacklisted but not `Jerry`, or vice versa? Should be both or none, IMhO.

Answer (score 4):

[unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unix) and [linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linux) were both blacklisted; I'm not sure why (I guess they're probably misused quite a bit, or at least perceived to be). We'll have to wait for a dev to read this I guess