# Unix tagging vs linux tagging?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tagging

Why is the [unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unix) tag not allowed while the [linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linux) tag is allowed? While asking questions I noticed that I can tag [linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linux) but when its time for [unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unix), you cannot tag Unix, why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have a [unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unix) tag but because the entire site is effectively about Unix this tag would get abused and become pointless. Therefore it's restricted to only historical aspects of Unix. There are a few Q&A's that use it (currently 9 Q's).

If you take a look at the info about the topic it explains its purpose and role:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/unix/info

(In more detail: Stack Exchange developers decided in 2011 that the names of the individual Stack Exchange sites should be blacklisted as tags.  So initially *both* [unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unix) *and* [linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linux) were blacklisted.  People objected to blacklisting [linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linux) at https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/565/5132 and the blacklisting was removed.)