# Architecture tag name confusing

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

I recently noticed a [couple of questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/15655/1925) tagged [architecture](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/architecture) that don't make any sense to me. I clicked through to make sure I knew what the architecture tag was supposed to be and discovered a hodge-podge of stuff. It looks like it was [originally created](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/168/1925) with the processor architecture in mind, but that's not fully clear any more.

Could the tag perhaps be renamed [cpu-architecture](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cpu-architecture) so that people don't randomly tag stuff with it without realizing what it's supposed to be about?

Answer (score 2):

I authoritatively declare that the creator of [architecture](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/architecture) meant it for questions about the design or architecture of unix systems, i.e. how the core stuff works. That's what it currently means on 8 of the 10 questions that now have it. On the other 2, it means CPU architecture.

I'm not opposed to renaming it; I proposed [design](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design) as an alternative earlier, but I'm open to other suggestions.

Ok for [cpu-architecture](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cpu-architecture).

Whatever we decide, let's document it in the tag wikis. (Back then the tag wiki edit rules were different, I suspect I didn't have the right to write one.)

Comment: Pardon my misunderstanding. The name [tag:design] strikes me as prone to ambiguity as well, but documenting would help. I don't know that we need a [tag:cpu-architecture], I was just trying to un-muddle what was what in my head.