# Don't allow posts with only the linux tag

Tags: feature-request, tags

I'm starting to change my mind about the [linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linux) tag. It was originally blacklisted with [unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unix), but we had it [reversed](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/561/the-linux-tag-is-not-allowed) because there are [legitimate uses](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109/why-is-there-a-linux-tag). But over and over again I see it misused -- two posts today used it as the *only* tag, so it's just letting them circumvent the tagging system entirely

I know people find it useful, so I don't want it eliminated, but is it possible to prevent users from tagging posts *only* [linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linux)? I don't think such a feature currently exists in the engine, but it would be useful

Comment: I'm convinced that this is fighting windmills. If the `linux` tag is rejected, people will use some other random tag like `bash` (which they already do, even for questions where the only connection with bash is that maybe one solution will involve typing something on a command line).

Comment: I think a `/linux` tag is useful. It's also useful to have an admixture of tags to some extent. Is what you describe a common thing Michael? Or is today an outlier? If it's not that common isn't it just a job for the mods to clean up tags where necessary? The mods are the people with the in-depth knowledge here and are probably the ones that can best distil the question to its constituent ideas. Just a thought.

Comment: @boehj Technically it's a job for [tag editors](http://unix.stackexchange.com/privileges/retag-questions) to clean up; normally Gilles does it. Obviously it can be dealt with, but if there's no case where we want just the `linux` tag on a post it makes sense to me to just not allow that to happen. Gilles points out that the `linux` tag isn't unique in that way though

Comment: Example: [This question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/14337) was initially tagged `bash`+`shell`, but it's fundamentally about `symlink`, and also about `find`, but not really about `bash` or `shell`.

Comment: @Gilles I'm sure there are many examples, but I don't know how "there are other tagging problems" means "we shouldn't solve this case"

Answer (score 5):

As of the last data dump, [935 questions started off with a single tag](http://data.stackexchange.com/unix%20and%20linux/q/101858/number-of-tags-in-the-first-revision-of-a-post) (out of [3830 questions](http://data.stackexchange.com/unix%20and%20linux/s/1431/number-of-posts), so that's almost 25%). Out of these, 88 (9.4%) started off with [linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linux), 55 (5.9%) with [bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bash), 32 (3.4%) with [command-line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-line).

I'd be interested to know how many of these had other tags added subsequently, but that's well beyond my SQL skills.

I don't think the numbers justify a new technical measure. During that period, I [made 1059 tag edits](http://data.stackexchange.com/unix%20and%20linux/s/1434/number-of-edits-by-a-given-user). Blocking questions from having only [linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linux) would hardly make a dent.